# Visibility of single read or write operation in multithreaded environment

Tags: multithreading

I have a question related to visibility of single read or write operation in multithreaded environment. Here is code (pure C):

```
volatile int flag = 0; // Global flag
```

Thread A does:

```
flag = 1;
```

Thread B checks flag variable:

```
while (!flag); // Wait for flag

doSomething();
```

Is there any visibilty issue here with reading flag variable in thread B?
Do I need to to do anything to ensure visibilty of flag in thread B. Like, inserting memory barriers.

Basically my question raised from lock free algorithms. Lock free algorithms are based on local copy concept.
This is I got from " Lock-Free Programming on AMD Multi-Core Systems" article:

> The simplest scenario for memory sharing using CAS is this:
>
> 1. a thread loads a value from shared memory, storing that value locally.
> 2. Then it does some calculations on that value, yielding a new value.
> 3. Finally, it attempts to update the original memory location using CAS, submitting both >the new value and the old value for comparison.

```
for(;;)
{
    tail = Q->Tail;
    next = tail->next;

    if (tail == Q->Tail)
    {
       if (next == NULL)
       {

         if (CAS( &tail->next, NULL, new_node)) break;
       }
       else
       {
          CAS( &Q->Tail, tail, next);
       }
    }
}

CAS( &Q->Tail, tail, new_node);
```

So I am wondering is there any visibilty issue we need to care when we do  tail = Q->Tail;?
I have googled a lot but still confused and want to get clear understanding.

Best regards,  Denis

Answer (score 0):

Since you marked the variable as volatile, the compiler won't try to cache the value in a register which takes care of your visibility problem. Doesn't hurt to double-check the generated assembly though.

You should still be careful about either your compiler or your CPU re-ordering the write operation. If the code in your `dosomething()` function depends on a write that happens in the other thread, you'll need to use some [memory barriers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) to preserve the order of the instructions.

As an example:

```
volatile int flag = 0;
volatile int value = 0;

...

value = 1;
flag = 1;

...

while (!flag);
if (!value) { ... }
dosomething();
```

Here the compiler is free to do the following optimization:

```
flag = 1;
value = 1;
```

This will work fine 99% of the time but, every once in a while, the thread will be interrupted between the two writes which invariably causes "interesting" debugging sessions. To avoid this you have to put a compiler memory barrier before the write to flag. This will indicate to the compiler that whatever is before the barrier has to happen before the barrier.

Even after doing that, you still have a bug. A lot of CPUs use something called [Out-of-order execution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_order_execution). While your processor guarantees that no problems will occur in purely sequential code, concurrent code requires that a certain order of reads and writes be maintained. As the name implies, the CPU makes no such guarantee and you might end up with the same situation you tried to avoid using the compiler barrier. The fix is to place a CPU memory barrier at the same spot as the compiler memory barrier. This will tell the CPU to finish and commit any pending reads or writes before continuing with the next instruction.

Note that I just recently de-mystified this issue for myself so I hope I got all that right.